# Why won't my PS4 give me my trophy?

Tags: achievements, assassins-creed-4-black-flag, ps4

I was playing Assassins Creed 4 when PSN logged me off but I kept playing and defeated all the legendary ships which is supposed to give you a trophy and I got no trophy. So I signed back in but still nothing. I can't go platinum in this game now!

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you defeated all 4 of them?

Comment: @Loko It's actually 5 ships. One fight is against 2 legendary ships simultaneously. ;)

Comment: @Nolonar Aha ok my bad

Comment: Is there not a way to start a new save and complete the achievement in that playthrough to get the last trophy?

Comment: I had this same issue, I just gave up on figuring it out.

Comment: @AdamV, you could. But it would take quite a decent amount of time to get your ship up to that level of capability. Unless you were **really** good. They aren't quick and easy fights.

Answer (score 1):

I know PS4 has had problems with game files recently and they're looking into it. It might just be a case of re-doing the game, a pain I know but there might not be another way

http://www.techhive.com/article/2090200/sony-grapples-with-save-killing-playstation-4-bug.html

Comment: This is likely unrelated. I've seen the bug in Battlefield 4. The game just crashes, and when you launch the game again, your savegame is corrupted and you have to start a new game. In my case, Battlefield 4 just replaced my old corrupted savegame against a fresh new one.